# apache rewriteengine match everything - error 500

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do a very basic rewrite that matches every URL and simply inserts "prod/".  Here's what's in .htaccess (I'm on a shared server):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ prod/$1
```

This is causing a server internal error - 500.  I can write a more specific rule, such as

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ prod/index.html
```

which works fine.

Comment: I see two issues.  Relative substitutions with mod_rewrite are really problematic, and you have no loop protection here (each time you substitute in htaccess, the entire ruleset runs again with the resulting path)

Comment: The whole rule set?  I thought it only continued with subsequent rules in the set.  (BTW I refined my question).  Also, what is a relative subst in this context?

Comment: In htaccess, the end result is interpreted as a new URL and re-injected into the server -- rewrite starts fresh with that new input.  The [END] flag was added to try to short-circuit that.

A relative substitution is when the 2nd parm isn't a full URL or a path starting with "/".  mod_rewrite has to take the directory of the htaccess file and try to strip some off to determine what part of the URL brought it there -- see the RewriteBase directive.    It is very confusing.

Comment: Your followup edit avoids the looping issue. The general way would be to look for e.g.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !prod/

Or use the [END] flag when you tack on prod/ the first time but that will skip all subsequent rules too and might come back to haunt you later.

Comment: This is starting to make sense!  So, with the RewriteCond you suggest, it only matches the first time.  To generalize that cond, don't I need something like !prod(/(.*))? to match anything not strarting with prod?

Comment: You don't need the trailing stuff, the regex can match w/o accounting for what extra stuff might come before/after

Comment: Oh, of course.  Thanks!  If you put this in the form of an answer, I'll give you due credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to (at least) avoid looping w/ e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/prod/
```

I would also be cautious about that relative substitution -- see the complexity discussed in the RewriteBase manual.

Comment: note: there is no leading ^ intentionally since the substitution is not /prod/$1